# Express.js redirect loop - Production Only

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect-loop

I am running an app with separated API and Front, both running on Express.js.

I have created a redirect on API to redirect '/' and missing routes to frontend URL. 
Everything works on dev, however, **I get a redirect loop - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error on production**.
Production is working on **https**, so I am not sure if that could be the problem, and **I am using Helmet package for security**.

Tried to create 2 solutions and searched through SO, but none work:

-----  #1 - app.js -----

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  //log error   
  logging.error(err);
  res.status(err.status || 500);

  // frontUrl is http://xx.com for dev, and https://xy.com for production
  res.redirect(frontUrl);
});

module.exports = app;
```

----- #2 - app.js -----

```
// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  //log error   
  logging.error(err);
  res.status(err.status || 500);

res.redirect('/');
});

module.exports = app;
```

-----  /routes/index.js -----

```
var frontUrl = require('../config.json').FrontURL;

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect(frontUrl);
});
```

Comment: are you sure frontUrl is defined in production, no typo etc? seems to me you are redirecting to yourself in app1

Comment: @JohannesMerz I was getting frontUrl same way as in case #2 and it is correct url. 
var frontUrl = require('../config.json').FrontURL;

Comment: your config clearly is sth else or it wouldnt be production. Have you checked if you misspelled anything in there? If not, is the redirect loop happening in app1 or does it reach app2?

Comment: @JohannesMerz I build dev and production and run them from /dev and /prod respectively, so they keep the same filenames and structure.

/dev/config.json has FrontURL = 'http://xx.com' 
/prod/config.json has FrontURL = 'https://xy.com/

Both cases cause redirect loop on production, and both are ok in development.

Comment: what happens when you hit the frontUrl directly and not through your api?

Comment: @JohannesMerz 
Trying to access it directly with https -> works
Trying to access with http -> redirects to https -> works

Since I have in app.js something like: 
app.use('/', indexRoutes);

which hits in routes/index.js

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect(frontUrl);
});

I still get redirect loop. I was thinking that my error handlers in app.js are faulty, but appears not :/